# Face Detection in JavaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have the following code to detect faces.

```
public class FaceDetection {


    public static final String XML_FILE = 
                    " C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";


            public static void main(String[] args){

                IplImage img = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Ioanna/Desktop/lena.png");       
                detect(img);        
            }   

            public static void detect(IplImage src){

                CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new 
                        CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(XML_FILE));
                CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
                CvSeq sign = cvHaarDetectObjects(
                        src,
                        cascade,
                        storage,
                        1.5,
                        3,
                        CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

                cvClearMemStorage(storage);

                int total_Faces = sign.total();     

                for(int i = 0; i < total_Faces; i++){
                    CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(sign, i));
                    cvRectangle (
                            src,
                            cvPoint(r.x(), r.y()),
                            cvPoint(r.width() + r.x(), r.height() + r.y()),
                            CvScalar.RED,
                            2,
                            CV_AA,
                            0);

                }

                cvShowImage("Result", src);
                cvWaitKey(0);

            }           

}
```

When it runs return the following error

OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Invalid classifier cascade) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp, line 1514
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ......\src\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp:1514: error: (-27) Invalid classifier cascade

```
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(Native Method)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(opencv_objdetect.java:238)
at FaceDetection.FaceDetection.detect(FaceDetection.java:32)
at FaceDetection.FaceDetection.main(FaceDetection.java:24)
```

Do anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: your filename starts with a blank

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not notice

Answer (score 0):

Copy the link `C:/Users/Ioanna/Desktop/lena.png`
and paste it in the file of the class and Copy the link `C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`
and paste it in the file of the class

[image]

```
public static final String XML_FILE = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
IplImage img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");
```